# Laravel 5.6. How I can use variables in WHERE condition?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm try get result:

```
$return = \App\session_results::
        where([                    
        ['sessia', session_id()],
        ['search_key', $number] //number = 322
        ])->get();
```

This code return 0 rows

And when I use

```
$return = \App\session_results::
    where([                    
    ['sessia', session_id()],
    ['search_key', '322']
    ])->get();
```

this code return good result.

How I can get result with variables?

Comment: Could you do `dd($number);` just before the query to see if the variable is really set?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, I just added an operator between the column name and your desired value.

```
$return = \App\session_results::where([
   ['sessia', '=', session_id()],
   ['search_key', '=', $number]
])->get();
```

Comment: Try to check if $number has been set in the controller. Just place `dd($number)` after $return

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this -

```
$return = \App\session_results::where(function ($query) use ($number) {
    $query->where('sessia', '=', session_id());
    $query->where('search_key', '=', $number);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

My contoller function use 2 input variables: $brand and $number.

```
 public function Show(Request $request, $brand, $number) {
}
```

And I have route

```
Route::GET('/{number}/{brand}', [
'uses' => 'partsFinder@Show',
'as' => 'parts.show',
]);
```

And I think, that $number is {number}, $brand is {brand}. But the order of the variables was not respected. #facepalm

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast `number` as `String` like this

```
$return = \App\session_results::
        where([                    
        ['sessia', session_id()],
        ['search_key', ''.$number.''] //number = 322
        ])->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

change your query to

```
$return = \App\session_results::where(['sessia' => session_id(), 'search_key' => $number ])->get();
```

or

```
$return = \App\session_results::where('sessia', session_id())->where('search_key', $number)->get();
```

Comment: Are you sure $number is set before this query ?